# uninstallAppsDisabled not working as expected

Tags: android-management-api

When using uninstallAppsDisabled with an Application installed as AVAILABLE, after the user installs, they can long hold on the app icon and see a popup menu with Uninstall as an option.  If selected, the app seems to uninstall but it never finishes.  Also, the app is no longer available to open either.

My thinking was that uninstallAppsDisabled = true would not allow the uninstall menu option to even appear on the device.

Also, with uninstallAppsDisabled = true, the apps on the device can still be uninstalled via the policy which is the opposite of what the documentation states.

Answer (score 2):

Setting [uninstallAppsDisabled](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies) is expected to prevent both users and admins (via policy) from uninstalling apps. A prompt stating “Action Not Allowed” will also be shown if a user attempts to manually uninstall an app.  What device/launcher are you using to test this functionality?

Comment: I am using Galaxy A12 and not using a custom launcher